# Randomly replace values at a set frequency

Tags: python

I am trying to replace values from a list. However, I would like to be able to set the frequency for which this occurs. I would like to provide values (max and min) for the number of values that are replaced. For example. I would like to be able to set the max number of values to be replaced a 5 and the minimum at 0, meaning that any given line, at most 5 values will be replaced but there is a possibility that none are replaced. The numbers could be anything values though, I don't want to just limit myself to 5 and 0 haha. I know this sounds bizarre but for the type of analysis I want to perform, the needs to be some kind of set frequency.

Based on previous posts, I have been able to find ways to randomly replace values but I haven't been able to find anything that talked about setting how frequent the random replacement occurs.

The code that I am using looks like this

```
import random
vals = ['*','1','0']
with open("test2.txt","w") as out:
    with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            li=line.strip()
            tabs = li.split("\t")
            geno = tabs[1:]
            print(geno)
            for index, x in enumerate(geno):
                if random.randint(0, 1):
                    geno[index] = random.choice(vals)
            print(geno)
```

an example of a list that is being used looks like this

```
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

A few example lines from my data to help out with your answer

```
AAD -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   1   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   1   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -
AAC 0   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   1   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   -   0   0   0   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   0   -   -   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   0   0   -   0   0   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   0   -   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   0   -   -
```

Comment: (1) For every line, use `n = random.randint(0, 5)` to figure how many indexes to change. (2) Use `random.sample(range(len(population)), n)` to get `n` random indexes in the list. (3) Change them.

Comment: @AKX oh wow, that makes perfect sense. Could you expand on point 3 in your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

```
import random


def replace_random_indexes(lst, min_n, max_n, replacements):
    # (1) Figure out how many indexes to change.
    n = random.randint(min_n, max_n)
    if n == 0:  # No changes required? Return original list.
        return lst
    # (2) Get a random set of indexes to change.
    indexes = set(random.sample(range(len(lst)), n))
    # (3) Using a list comprehension, return a new list with the indexes
    #     from `indexes` changed to a random choice from `replacements`.
    return [
        random.choice(replacements)
        if index in indexes
        else value
        for index, value
        in enumerate(lst)
    ]

orig = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for i in range(10):
    print(replace_random_indexes(orig, 0, 3, ["a", "b", "c"]))
```

This prints out e.g.

```
[1, 'a', 'a', 'c', 5, 6, 7]
['a', 2, 'c', 'a', 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a']
[1, 'a', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'a']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'c', 'c']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 'b', 5, 'c', 'c']
```

You can note that no list has more than 3 items changed.

To plug that into your original program,

```
vals = ["*", "1", "0"]
with open("test2.txt", "w") as out, open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[1:]
        new_geno = replace_random_indexes(geno, 0, 5, vals)
        print(new_geno)
```

or similar should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) from Numpy, assigning frequencies to events.

I'm simplifying what you're doing somewhat, but hopefully this demonstrates the principle. You have three events (`*`, `0`, and `1`) and the probabilities of each event are `0.1`, `0.6`, and `0.3`, respectively.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy as np

elements = ['AAD', 'AAC']
events = ['*', '0', '1']
event_freqs = [0.1, 0.6, 0.3]
n_events = 10

assert(sum(event_freqs) == 1)
rng = np.random.default_rng()

for i,v in enumerate(elements):
    sample = rng.multinomial(1, event_freqs, size=n_events)
    hits = np.where(sample == 1)[1].tolist()
    sys.stdout.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(v, '\t'.join([events[x] for x in hits])))
```

This is basically like repeatedly flipping a three-sided coin, which is biased for heads, tails, and the coin edge.

Sample output:

```
$ python so69831882.py
AAD     1       1       0       1       *       0       0       *       1       0
AAC     0       *       *       1       0       1       0       *       1       0
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was after; they wanted to change a certain number of random elements in their lists, not generate new lists with given distributions.

Comment: @AKX is right, but I do think this is an incredible answer. I didn't mention this in my question so this is my fault, but I do need to change certain numbers rather than generate a new list.

Comment: As an aside, you might not need Numpy for this, since [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) is a thing since Python 3.6 :)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. However, if you're doing bioinformatics or general data science, it's not a terrible idea to pick up a little Numpy as you go along. It's a pretty extensive kit and will do a lot of statistical and matrix work quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a separate function to feed your lists of characters to:

```
import random
def random_swapper(big_list, swap_list=['*','1','0'], min_swaps=1, max_swaps=5,test=False):
    n=len(big_list)
    swap_count=random.randint(min_swaps,max_swaps)
    swap_indices=list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(swap_indices)
    for idx in swap_indices[:swap_count]:
        new_val=random.choice(swap_list)
        big_list[idx]=new_val
        if test:print(swap_count,end=' swaps:  ')
    return big_list
```

and test it:

```
for _ in range(10):
list1=['X']*20
print(random_swapper(list1, swap_list=['*','1','0'], min_swaps=1, max_swaps=5,test=True))
```

which returns

```
5 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', '1', '1', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '*', 'X']
4 swaps:  ['X', 'X', '*', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '*', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
4 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', '*', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', '0']
1 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
2 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '*', 'X', 'X']
3 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '*', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '*']
4 swaps:  ['X', '0', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
1 swaps:  ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
5 swaps:  ['X', '*', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', '1', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
5 swaps:  ['X', '0', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '1', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', '*', 'X']
```

and plug it into the rest of your code:

```
vals = ['*','1','0']
with open("test2.txt","w") as out:
    with open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            li=line.strip()
            tabs = li.split("\t")
                geno = tabs[1:]
            print(geno)
            random_swapper(geno,swap_list=vals,min_swaps=1,max_swaps=5,test=False)
            print(geno)
```