# Random replace only on select indices at a set frequency

Tags: python

I am trying to replace data at a set frequency only on select columns. With the help of AKX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831882/randomly-replace-values-at-a-set-frequency), I was able to find a solution to randomly replace values across an entire list. I feel bad for asking the question because I already asked a similar question, however, I am can't seem to really find a solution to do this regardless. So what I am trying to do exactly is, if I have a list that contains 4 values, I want to be able to select which values are randomly being replaced based on their indices. For example, if I select indices 2 and 4, I only want to replace values in those indices but indices 1 and 3 remain unaltered.

```
vals = ["*"]
def replace_random(lst, min_n, max_n, replacements):
    n = random.randint(min_n, max_n)
    if n == 0: 
        return lst
    indexes = set(random.sample(range(len(lst)), n))
    return [
        random.choice(replacements)
        if index in indexes
        else value
        for index, value
        in enumerate(lst)
    ]
```

example of applying

```
with open("test2.txt", "w") as out, open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[1:]
        new_geno = replace_random_indexes(geno, 0, 5, vals)
        print(new_geno)
```

example me what I have been trying to do to achieve the goal:

```
M = [1,3]
with open("test2.txt", "w") as out, open("test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[1:]
        new_geno = replace_random_indexes(geno[M], 0, 1, vals)
        print(new_geno)
```

However, I get the following error when I try this:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Example data:
Input:

```
123 1   2   1   4
234 -   2   0   4
345 -   2   -   4
456 0   2   1   4
567 1   2   1   4
678 0   2   0   4
789 -   2   1   4
890 0   2   1   4
```

Output:

```
123 1   *   1   4
234 -   2   0   4
345 -   2   -   *
456 0   2   1   *
567 1   2   1   4
678 0   2   0   4
789 -   2   1   4
890 0   *   1   4
```

**Edit:**

One thing I forgot to mention, I thought about just removing the indices that I did not want to edit, then performing the replacement on the indices that I do want to replace, however, I wasn't sure how to join the indices back together in the same order. Here is what I tried

```
with open("test2.txt", "w") as out, open("start.test.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[1:]
        geno_alt = [i for j, i in enumerate(geno) if j not in M]
        geno_alt = replace_random(geno_alt,0,1,vals)
        print(geno_alt)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve - your code is more complex than it needs to be (and contains a few errors). You say you "want to be able to select which values are randomly being replaced based on their indices" - how do you want to select these indices? Pass a list of values as well as a list of indices? Would this be some sort of mask that gets repeated over the entire list, or does it cover the entire list? Or do you want to pass some sort of frequency instead? (e.g. 0.5 to replace half the values) Can you provide an example of inputs and a sample matching output?

Comment: I was to be able to give indices that I select. In your answer, it is exactly what I want to do. I want to pass a list of indices. So for example, if I give a list of 2 and 4 then I replace values in those indices, very similar to your answer. I want this to occur over the entire file, where only those indices are being changed while the remaining indices remain untouched

Comment: @Grismar I added an output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is replace values at specific indices on each line of a file (taking the example data you provided), making n replacements (n randomly selected from some range), with a randomly selected replacement from some values, this would work:

```py
from random import sample, choice


def make_replacements(fn_in, fn_out, indices, values, frequency):
    with open(fn_out, "w") as out, open(fn_in, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            indices_sample = sample(indices, choice(frequency))
            line = '\t'.join(
                choice(values)
                if n in indices_sample
                else v
                for n, v in enumerate(line.strip().split())
            ) + '\n'
            out.write(line)


make_replacements("start.test.txt", "out.txt", [2, 4], ['*'], [0, 1])
```

An example output:

```
123 1   2   1   *
234 -   2   0   4
345 -   2   -   4
456 0   2   1   4
567 1   2   1   *
678 0   *   0   4
789 -   2   1   *
890 0   2   1   *
```

I've updated the code and example output according to your changes in the question and the comments and believe this is what you were after.

Comment: That is very close to what I was looking for. However, with the frequency, what I was referring to was the number of values that will be changed. For example, if the frequency was set to 0 to 1, then either 0 values will be changed, or in the next line may be 1 value will be changed. If the frequency was set to 1 to 2, then maybe 2 values will be changed, and then the next line, maybe 2 values again, will be changed, and then the next line might have 1 value changed.

Comment: I played with your answer a bit and was able to alter your answer to fit my needs. Will still keep your answer as the accepted answer. I just wanted to share my solution for completeness. Thank you again for your help. Let me know if you see any obvious bugs in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given by Grismar and the answer given by AKX in my last post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831882/randomly-replace-values-at-a-set-frequency), I was able to come up with this answer to solve my problem.

```
import random
def select_replacements(lst, indices, min_n, max_n, values):
    n = random.randint(min_n, max_n)
    if n == 0:
        return lst
    indices_sample = random.sample(indices, n)
    return [ 
        random.choice(values)
        if n in indices_sample
        else v
        for n, v in enumerate(last)
    ]
```

program:

```
with open("test2.txt", "w") as out, open("start.test2.txt", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = line.strip()
        tabs = li.split("\t")
        geno = tabs[1:]
        geno = select_replacements(geno, [1, 3], ['*'], 0,2)
        geno = '\t'.join(geno)
        merge = (f"{tabs[0]}\t{geno}\n")
        out.write(merge)
```

input:

```
123 1   2   1   4
234 -   2   0   4
345 -   2   -   4
456 0   2   1   4
567 1   2   1   4
678 0   2   0   4
789 -   2   1   4
890 0   2   1   4
```

output:

```
123 1   2   1   4
234 -   *   0   4
345 -   *   -   *
456 0   *   1   4
567 1   *   1   *
678 0   *   0   *
789 -   2   1   4
890 0   *   1   *
```